# Mapbox layer doesn't update on variable change | react-map-gl

Tags: postgis, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have a map with a custom layer. Right now I have a problem that when points state get updated the map doesn't rerender. How can I force a rerender of the map layer when points changes? Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-jasper-p8xeme?file=/src/Map.jsxfile=/src/Map.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import MapGL from "react-map-gl";
const interpolateHeatmapLayer = require("interpolateheatmaplayer");

const MapDisplay = () => {
  const mapRef = React.useRef();
  const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
    longitude: 12.1828,
    latitude: 65.5926,
    zoom: 3,
    bearing: 0,
    pitch: 0
  });
  function handleChange() {
    setPoints(points.slice(0, 5));
  }
  const [points, setPoints] = useState([
    {
      lat: 69.3073,
      lon: 16.1312,
      val: -6
    },
    {
      lat: 59.9423,
      lon: 10.72,
      val: -2
    },
    {
      lat: 59.6193,
      lon: 10.215,
      val: -3
    },
    {
      lat: 61.8957,
      lon: 7.8955,
      val: -9
    },
    {
      lat: 61.122,
      lon: 9.063,
      val: -8
    },
    {
      lat: 62.3293,
      lon: 5.268,
      val: 3
    },
    {
      lat: 61.0917,
      lon: 10.4762,
      val: -7
    },
    {
      lat: 60.7022,
      lon: 6.9373,
      val: -4
    },
    {
      lat: 61.2928,
      lon: 5.0443,
      val: 1
    },
    {
      lat: 59.23,
      lon: 10.3483,
      val: -29
    },
    {
      lat: 61.5648,
      lon: 7.9957,
      val: -11
    },
    {
      lat: 64.1587,
      lon: 12.4692,
      val: -8
    },
    {
      lat: 69.3695,
      lon: 24.4312,
      val: -18
    },
    {
      lat: 59.8558,
      lon: 10.4358,
      val: -3
    },
    {
      lat: 61.6595,
      lon: 7.2762,
      val: -5
    },
    {
      lat: 58.507,
      lon: 6.5045,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 63.4597,
      lon: 10.9305,
      val: -3
    },
    {
      lat: 64.7977,
      lon: 10.5493,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 69.6537,
      lon: 18.9368,
      val: -4
    },
    {
      lat: 59.6605,
      lon: 10.7818,
      val: -3
    },
    {
      lat: 59.2852,
      lon: 11.1128,
      val: -1
    },
    {
      lat: 59.3742,
      lon: 10.798,
      val: -1
    },
    {
      lat: 70.2452,
      lon: 19.4997,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 62.6043,
      lon: 9.6667,
      val: -7
    },
    {
      lat: 66.8102,
      lon: 13.9793,
      val: -1
    },
    {
      lat: 60.7733,
      lon: 10.8055,
      val: -5
    },
    {
      lat: 61.4648,
      lon: 10.1277,
      val: -8
    },
    {
      lat: 58.6592,
      lon: 5.5553,
      val: 3
    },
    {
      lat: 58.3988,
      lon: 8.7893,
      val: 2
    },
    {
      lat: 61.2042,
      lon: 2.2687,
      val: 4
    },
    {
      lat: 59.1513,
      lon: 10.8288,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 60.383,
      lon: 5.3327,
      val: 2
    },
    {
      lat: 58.3711,
      lon: 1.9091,
      val: 6
    },
    {
      lat: 58.8565,
      lon: 9.5745,
      val: 1
    },
    {
      lat: 63.4107,
      lon: 10.4538,
      val: -4
    },
    {
      lat: 59.6479,
      lon: 6.3499,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 58.109,
      lon: 6.5675,
      val: 2
    },
    {
      lat: 59.0272,
      lon: 10.5242,
      val: 1
    },
    {
      lat: 63.4882,
      lon: 10.8795,
      val: -4
    },
    {
      lat: 59.9847,
      lon: 10.6693,
      val: -4
    },
    {
      lat: 68.1535,
      lon: 14.6485,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 61.7873,
      lon: 6.1835,
      val: -1
    },
    {
      lat: 56.5434,
      lon: 3.2244,
      val: 5
    },
    {
      lat: 60.9345,
      lon: 10.0358,
      val: -7
    },
    {
      lat: 59.5766,
      lon: 7.3897,
      val: -7
    },
    {
      lat: 61.0272,
      lon: 5.3813,
      val: 1
    },
    {
      lat: 60.2065,
      lon: 11.0802,
      val: -5
    },
    {
      lat: 68.9968,
      lon: 23.0335,
      val: -18
    },
    {
      lat: 61.6513,
      lon: 10.1082,
      val: -9
    },
    {
      lat: 62.6785,
      lon: 8.5473,
      val: -1
    },
    {
      lat: 65.2023,
      lon: 10.9965,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 60.7002,
      lon: 10.8695,
      val: -5
    },
    {
      lat: 69.7255,
      lon: 29.8977,
      val: -11
    },
    {
      lat: 66.7628,
      lon: 12.486,
      val: 1
    },
    {
      lat: 69.2349,
      lon: 17.9014,
      val: -5
    },
    {
      lat: 58.0732,
      lon: 8.0532,
      val: 2
    },
    {
      lat: 58.34,
      lon: 8.5225,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 59.3822,
      lon: 9.2128,
      val: -2
    },
    {
      lat: 65.7017,
      lon: 11.8562,
      val: 0
    },
    {
      lat: 68.7553,
      lon: 23.5387,
      val: -17
    },
    {
      lat: 69.6005,
      lon: 17.8312,
      val: -1
    },
    {
      lat: 62.034,
      lon: 4.986,
      val: 2
    },
    {
      lat: 65.32285,
      lon: 7.3156,
      val: 3
    },
    {
      lat: 59.7662,
      lon: 7.3653,
      val: -6
    },
    {
      lat: 70.3707,
      lon: 31.0962,
      val: -3
    },
    {
      lat: 69.9775,
      lon: 23.3582,
      val: -8
    },
    {
      lat: 64.1727,
      lon: 9.4052,
      val: 1
    },
    {
      lat: 60.9785,
      lon: 9.224,
      val: -8
    },
    {
      lat: 69.6767,
      lon: 18.9133,
      val: -4
    },
    {
      lat: 70.06,
      lon: 24.9793,
      val: -10
    }
  ]);
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (points) {
      console.log(points);
      const InterPolateLayer = interpolateHeatmapLayer.create({
        points: points,
        layerID: "Interpolate",
        p: 2,
        maxValue: 20,
        minValue: -20,
        roi: [
          {
            lat: 58.876757827896306,
            lon: 11.881643616280888
          },
          {
            lat: 58.82822263473829,
            lon: 11.186346643290852
          },
          {
            lat: 57.912686819868505,
            lon: 7.476790555439328
          },
          {
            lat: 58.312298449537096,
            lon: 5.6030650517562375
          },
          {
            lat: 59.29308944955574,
            lon: 4.597435154638623
          },
          {
            lat: 62.044315808590355,
            lon: 4.497823276243542
          },
          {
            lat: 63.90167395134969,
            lon: 8.386691071710919
          },
          {
            lat: 65.78132314149487,
            lon: 10.969111182413434
          },
          {
            lat: 68.99622052100831,
            lon: 12.799815394602154
          },
          {
            lat: 71.32599822634651,
            lon: 24.95207832070384
          },
          {
            lat: 70.40816832615413,
            lon: 33.75659034462962
          },
          {
            lat: 69.00071308527767,
            lon: 29.063824274263716
          },
          {
            lat: 68.54696459233939,
            lon: 24.900207080564833
          },
          {
            lat: 68.67151113738113,
            lon: 22.334051885328627
          },
          {
            lat: 63.99473920322428,
            lon: 13.975403465948437
          },
          {
            lat: 58.876757827896306,
            lon: 11.881643616280888
          }
        ]
      });
      mapRef.current.getMap().addLayer(InterPolateLayer, "road-label-medium");
    }
  }, [points]);
  return (
    <>
      {points && (
        <MapGL
          {...viewport}
          initialViewState={{
            longitude: 10.757933,
            latitude: 59.91149
          }}
          onViewportChange={setViewport}
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
          onLoad={onMapLoad}
          ref={mapRef}
          mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
          mapboxApiAccessToken="pk.eyJ1Ijoib2xlZHliZWRva2tlbiIsImEiOiJja3ljb3ZvMnYwcmdrMm5vZHZtZHpqcWNvIn0.9-uQhH-WQmh-IwrA6gNtUg"
        ></MapGL>
      )}
      <button onClick={handleChange}>CHange button</button>
    </>
  );
};
export default MapDisplay;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but when you're using react-map-gl, use the [source](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/source) and [layer](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/layer) components to add layers on your map. With the code something like:

```
<Source id="my-data" type="geojson" data={geojson}>
  <Layer {...layerStyle} />
</Source>
```

Which keeps the layers "reactive". There's no point of using react-map-gl if you're going to use the vanilla JS logic with useRef.